# Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS kernel does not upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

After recent update from Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (moving from base version of 18.04 GA kernel), kernel is not getting updated to 4.15.0-55.60

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-50-generic
```

Also tried to move to HWE kernel with the following

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

but still `uname -r` showing only `kernel 4.15.0-50 generic`

```
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic                               4.15.0-29.31                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic                               4.15.0-45.48                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic                               4.15.0-48.51                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic                               4.15.0-50.54                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic                               4.15.0-55.60                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic                                5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                                         4.15.0.55.57                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04                               5.0.0.23.80                                  amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Also tried

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic
```

but no change in kernel version.

Tried

```
$ sudo apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 is already the newest version (5.0.0.23.80).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

$ lsb_release -a

LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Release:    18.04

Codename:   bionic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel you mis is on your system.

> linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic                               4.15.0-55.60                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot.

Change boot device in Bios so the harddrive of bionic installation is the 1. Device. Or boot xenial and run `sudo update-grub` where.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. already tried that, no change in kernel version. $ uname -r
4.15.0-50-generic

Comment: Please show `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` and `sudo update-grub`

Comment: $[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
BIOS 
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-55-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-55-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-50-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-50-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (16.04) on /dev/sdb1
done

Comment: from xenial, issued sudo update-grub, now gnu grub 2 entry showing Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and $ uname -r 5.0.0-23-generic many thanks, great, god bless you.